# Calling a function with onClick and a variable as a param

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Code looks like:

```
response.data[i]._id = "myID";
console.log(response.data[i]._id = "myID"); // "myID"
$"(#myDiv").append('<button onClick="deletePost(response.data[i]._id);">Delete</button>');

function deletePost(postId) {
    console.log(postId);
}
```

When clicking that button, I get an error saying "response is not defined". How can I pass my value correctly inside that onClick function?

Comment: could you send the error log on your browser for the first one?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined `

Comment: Seems like it's passing the param as a string instead of the value from `response.data[i]._id`

Comment: so? is response a js variable, or a variable in a server side template engine, like jsp..

Comment: response is not in scope, it's going to need to be global. example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/VsPr9/

Comment: `response.data[i]._id` is available when I pass it to the onClick deletePost function as a param. Adding more to my post.

Comment: `$(#myDiv)` should be `$("#myDiv")`

Comment: Fixed in the post, typo when renaming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) binding.

```
response.data[i]._id = "myID";
$("#myDiv").append($('<button>').click(function () {
    deletePost (response.data[i]._id);
}).text('Delete'));
```